# Express NodeJs cookie doesn't expire

Tags: node.js, session, cookies

I am using Express4 to develop a web app(a simple twitter). 
I use npm package "express-session" to manage session and cookie.
But I did not set cookie.maxAge. Based on the [git document](https://github.com/expressjs/session) we have:

> By default cookie.maxAge is null, meaning no "expires" parameter is set so the cookie becomes a browser-session cookie. When the user closes the browser the cookie (and session) will be removed.

but actually, when I close my chrome and start it again, I still have the same cookie generated by server in last request.

Has anyone faced same problem? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
// This user should log in again after restarting the browser
req.session.cookie.expires = false;
```

> ```
>    Each session has a unique cookie object accompany it. This allows
>     you to alter the session cookie per visitor. For example we can
>     set req.session.cookie.expires to false to enable the cookie
>     to remain for only the duration of the user-agent.
> ```

Comment: thanks, I tried but this did not work.  After restarting my browser. The cookie is still in request header. I wonder that how could we see the cookie's expire property in client(browser)?

Comment: I figured it out. That is my stupid fault. I configure chrome as "run in background" so when I close the browser it is not really closed.